# Direction of a vector tangential on an arc with known radius, length end/start coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, approximation

I'm trying to calculate coordinates of a vector that is tangential to a specific curve with known start and end coordinates, radius and length. On top of that I know the vector's length. The vector starts at the start Point of the arc. The vector has of course a starting angle, but this does not matter at the moment. 
I can calculate vector's coordinates when it is a chord of the arc, but this principle does not give me a result good enough. 
I would be grateful for any help, thanks.

Edit: I know the start and end coordinates of an arc (circular arc) with known radius as well. Therefore the equation of the curve is known. 
I also know the tangential vector's length and its start point.

This is a drawing I made for easier visualization of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Ziga, it is not completely clear what the problem is. Lets make it more clear: You have a curve (probably smooth?) without knowing its equation/parameter form. You know a point $(X,Y)$, a length of a segment tangent to the curve and starting at $(X,Y)$ and finally some further "end" point $(X_e,Y_e)$. What about $R$? Is the other end of this segment (blue point) known? Also, do you search the point which is a cross section of the  green line with the curve, or the way you denoted it on the picture? Please provide clarifications via editing your post.

Comment: There exist an infinite number of different curves that have the same "start and end coordinates, radius and length".  Unless you are given a "formula" for the curve, or the curve is uniquely defined in some other way there no way to do that.  (You say the "radius" is determined.  Only a circle has a fixed radius.  If that is what you mean it is a much simpler problem.  Given $(x- a)^2+ (y- b)^2= R^2$, the equation of a circle with center at (a, b), radius R, then $(x- a)(dy/dx)+ 2(y- b)= 0$ so that $dy/dx= -(y- b)/(x- a)$.  The angle of the tangent line is $arctan(-(y- b)/(x- a))$.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I meant is an arc of course. And it is a circular arc, like you guessed.